# sharepoint workflow to create a new item in another list if it's not already existing

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow, infopath2010

I have two lists, A and B.
I want to create new item in list B once I submit an item in list A.
But, I want to check first if the item already exists in list B. If it exists, just update the existing item or delete it and create a new item instead.
can I achieve this using workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that should be doable. If this is a list workflow, I assume there is one field in the current item (Let's say "LookupID") that is the unique key (let's say "Title") for the second list.

Set a workflow variable to retrieve the ID of List2 where "Title" equals "LookupID".  If the variable contains a value, you can use it to update the existing list item, else create a new one.